# Partial editor to show single property of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my model as follows

```
 public class PlaceOrder
    {        
    public int orderCode { set; get; }
    public string Order_ID { set; get; }
    public int orderDetailCode { set; get; }
    [Required]
    public string Topic { set; get; }
    //50 more fields are there
    }
```

Using editorforModel displays all the fields in the model. I want to have a editor helper which takes the property name and only shows editor for that specific property.

I wrote a create/edit/details actions for my model and working fine. What my final goals is that I want to have edit button next to every field on the details view. As soon I click on edit it allows to update and validate the input as well

**EDIT**
I am using following snippet for edit link

```
 @(Html.Awe().PopupFormActionLink()
                   .LinkText("Edit")
                   .Name("editP")
                   .Url(Url.Action("PropertyEdit", "PlaceOrder", new
                               {

                                   PropertyName =   Html.NameFor(model => model.SubjectCategoryCode),
                                   propertyValue =  Html.IdFor(model => model.SubjectCategoryCode),
                                   ordercode = Model.orderCode
                               })
                       )
                    .Title("Editor for " + Html.NameFor(model => model.SubjectCategoryCode))
```

and I want something that I pass the field name and it dispalys the relevant fields and do the validation

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an EditorFor and a form for each field:

```
@using Html.BeginForm("action", "controller")
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ordercode)
    <input type="submit" />
}

@using Html.BeginForm("action", "controller")
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.orderDetailCode)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Of course, you would need a different action for each item and you need a way to get the other values as well, since you're only posting one value to the controller. To achieve this you could include a hidden field with the id and retrieve the other values on the server.

Comment: yes I can do this, but this doesn't seem viable as the number of fields grows. I want to have a generic Editorfor which takes the property name of the model and dispalys accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There's the `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Property)` method for this (your model should be set to `PlaceOrder` to use this helper, as with any statically typed helpers).

Edit: Bah, Kenneth was faster :-).